# Google recaptcha required for form submission

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I need help in order to validate our form to be submitted via google recaptcha, I have successfully implemented the code however the form still allows submission without the recaptcha, how do I make it required field? not very good with java script here, any assistance is greatly appreciated
also if an error message would pop up so that asking people to complete recaptcha that would be great, thanks a lot

CSS

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Html

```
<div class="form">

%form_errors%

<div align="right"><p><strong>* Denotes mandatory field</strong></p></div>


<fieldset>

<legend>Your enquiry details</legend>

<div class="form-row">
%question_label_746942_q7%
%question_field_746942_q7%
</div>

</fieldset>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="google site key"></div>
<div class="form-row-submit" align="right">

%submit_button%
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can by default set the submit button to disabled and only enable it on the callback function from reCAPTCHA.

Check this: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Make sure to validate the form on the server side too.

**UPDATE**

Add this in your :

```
<script>
    function enableBtn(){
        document.getElementById("submit_details").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```

And then call the above function in the reCAPTCHA div in your form as follows:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_KEY" data-callback="enableBtn"></div>
<button type="submit" id="submit_details" disabled>Send</button>
```

This will have the submit button disabled when the page loads so the user won't be able to submit the form. The button is enabled only after the user passes the "I'm not a robot" test.

Again, remember to validate the form data on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, needs a bit of details as not too good with java script, could I please get detailed steps as to what to do?

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I have tried to use your code however the send button is still disabled even if the recaptcha is ticked, also I want to use my own platform submit button with the style I have created, how do I go about that

Comment: What about when the validation expires the button remains clickable, how would I go about revoking ability to click the button when the validation expires?

Comment: @Third_Hyperion There is also a data-expired-callback that can be set (like data-callback) to disable the button again. (I realise after 3 years you probably don't care, but for google's benefit)

Comment: Brilliant answer. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateRecaptcha();">
</form>

<script>
function validateRecaptcha() {
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (response.length === 0) {
        alert("You need to fill the captcha");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("validated");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<button type="submit" id="submit_details" disabled>Send</button>`

Not `if="submit_details"`

The function is using `getElementById("submit_details")`, so it is looking for an ID of "submit_details" in order to remove the disabled condition of the button by setting `disabled = false` instead of `disabled = true` which is the default condition that is set inline in the `<button>` tag.